# TF Session graph is empty - Creating new tf graph from two imported graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

Right now, I am working with two models, one of which I load from a checkpoint, and the other I load a frozen model. Inside a class, I have a loadmodel function, and another processing function where I want to apply both of these models onto an image, so that when a future program can easily process everything on the image just by calling that method of the class.

Here is a simplified example of the code, for just the methods I am struggling with in the class:

```
def segmented_stylization(self, img, target_size = 3840):       
    self.g1 = self.seg_graph.as_graph_def()
    self.g2 = self.eval_graph.as_graph_def()
    start = time.time()  
    # Here we need to create a combined graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_combined:

        # Get both our stylized frame and segmentation mappings by passing in the original frame input 
        style_input = self.eval_graph.get_tensor_by_name("img_placeholder:0")
        style_output = self.eval_graph.get_tensor_by_name("style_outputs:0")            

        seg_input = self.seg_graph.get_tensor_by_name("ImageTensor:0")
        seg_output = self.seg_graph.get_tensor_by_name("SemanticPredictions:0")
        seg_map = seg_output[0]

        # Take our segmented mapping and identify the pixels corresponding to any human(s) in the picture
        hPixels = tf.where(tf.equal(seg_map, self.humanIdx))

        # Replace the pixels corresponding to a human 
        #mframe = tf.scatter_nd_update(style_output, hPixels, tf.gather_nd(resized_img, hPixels))

        # mframe = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(style_output (self.output_width, self.output_height))
        #mframe = tf.clip_by_value(mframe, 0, 255)

    sess_comb = tf.Session(graph = g_combined)
    a = sess_comb.run([hPixels], feed_dict = {"img_placeholder:0" : resized_img, "ImageTensor:0" : resized_img})

    output_img = sess_comb.run([mframe], feed_dict = {"img_placeholder:0" : resized_img, "ImageTensor:0" : resized_img})
    return output_img
```

The error I get above is

```
raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

I've also tried wrapping in the combined session in a with statement, trying both nested and outside but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Another thing I've tried instead was instead of get_tensor_by_name:

```
self.g1 = self.seg_graph.as_graph_def()
self.g2 = self.eval_graph.as_graph_def()
seg_output, = tf.import_graph_def(self.g1, input_map = {"ImageTensor:0" : resized_img, "img_placeholder:0" : resized_img}, return_elements = ["SemanticPredictions:0"])
style_output, = tf.import_graph_def(self.g2, input_map={"img_placeholder:0" : resized_img}, return_elements=["style_outputs:0"])
```

But this returns the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of node import/Shape was passed double from import/_inputs/Const:0 incompatible with expected uint8.
```

Any insight would appreciate it, thanks! Still new to tf :).

Comment: My guess is that the tensors that are being retrieved from the other graphs aren't properly being added to the new graph, since when I print out the tensor names in the new graph I end up with an empty set. Is there a special way I am supposed to go about adding them in?

Comment: Never mind, I think I resolved it... You should use the tf.import_graph_def() function after calling as_graph_def() on your other graphs. The ValueError was due to the inputs being of the wrong type that didn't match the types of the graphs.